System.NotSupportedException while testing function with Extension methods
when i call function for testing with given below code:
        [Fact]
        public async Task CreateEntryInDBSuccess()
        {
            //Arrange
            var expectedResult = "Message Added Successfully";
            CmsModel message = new CmsModel
            {
                id = "test",
            };
            CmsEntryToDbSchema entry = new CmsEntryToDbSchema
            {
                id = "test",
            };

            //_CmsAssetsCollection.Setup(x => x.InsertOne(It.IsAny<CmsEntryToDbSchema>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(entry));
            _cmsEntryCollectionMock.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<CmsEntryToDbSchema>>(), null)).Returns(new Mock<IFindFluent<CmsEntryToDbSchema, CmsEntryToDbSchema>>().Object);

            //Act
            var result = await _eventTriggerService.CreateEntryInDB(message);

            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(expectedResult, result);
        }

it shows error like

and this error is because of using Extension methods.how to resolve this
i am expecting proper testing for function
